# How can a worker thread end the application?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I seem to have the challenge that a worker thread knows to close the application, but neither `PostQuitMessage()` nor `Application.Terminate()` seem to work. The Application just doesn't quit, no errors.

Do I have to set a flag to call one of these from the main thread, or is there another trick?

The thread checks for an updated version and calls an updater to replace the `.exe` (once it's not locked anymore). After calling the updater, it needs to quit the application.

Comment: You apparently didn't try `ExitProcess(0)`. Still, are you sure the thread *should* be the one that terminates the application? [`PostQuitMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postquitmessage) doesn't work because you post it from the wrong thread: "The PostQuitMessage function posts a WM_QUIT message **to the thread's message queue** and returns immediately". `Application.Terminate` doesn't work because it is based on `PostQuitMessage`. Still: The right solution is probably to redesign so the main thread determines when it is time to quit.

Comment: I have added the info about why this thread "needs" to quit... :-/

Comment: (And of course this secondary thread may ask the main thread to quit, and then the main thread can do the actual quitting.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PostQuitMessage()` posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the message queue of the calling thread.  `Application.Terminate()` uses `PostQuitMessage()`.  That is why neither is working in your case, since you are calling them in the wrong thread context.

So, you can either:

- flag the main thread to call `PostQuitMessage()`/`Application.Terminate()` at its earliest conventience, such as with `TThread.Queue()`:

  `TThread.Queue(nil, Application.Terminate);`
- post your own `WM_QUIT` message to the main thread or `Application` window, ie:

  `PostThreadMessage(MainThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);`

  `PostMessage(Application.Handle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);`
- post a `WM_CLOSE` message to your `MainForm` window (if you have one) <sup>1</sup>, as closing the `MainForm` will terminate the Application, ie:

  `PostMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);`

  <sup>1: just be careful with this one! The `TWinControl.Handle` property is not thread-safe. If you read the MainForm's `Handle` property in a worker thread while the main thread is in the process of (re-)creating the window, bad things can happen!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Remy has a great answer.

If you are using The Delphi Threads (your threads derive from **TThread**) then you can use the **Synchronize** method of your thread to run a routine in the context of the main thread, and then in that routine (which is run by the main thread) you can call Application.Terminate

See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize